# NsisIIS - plugin requirements

Tags: iis, nsis

Does anyone know the requirements of the NsisIIS plugin?

I am getting this error:

`code:
Could not load: C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\nsb2.tmp\NsisIIS.dll`

This is on a Window Server 2003, which has IIS installed and running. I am logged onto the server as an adminsitrator.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin seems to require MSVCR100.DLL and MSVCP100.DLL so it probably needs the [Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5555). You should ask the [author](http://sourceforge.net/sendmessage.php?touser=1413198#kamyar1979) if he could create a statically linked version or use a older version of VC that links to MSVCRT.DLL (Or compile yourself, the source code is on sourceforge)

Comment: This does seem to with on Windows Server 2008, just gets ?????.exe has stopped working  :-(  I've even tried this on Server 2003 and it does not work either.